Getting incorrect time from influxQL
I have an influxQL query:
SELECT sum(“metrics written”) FROM (
SELECT max(“metrics_written”) - min(“metrics_written”) as “metrics written”
FROM “tsesre_gms”.“anonymous”.“internal_write”
WHERE time > now() - 5m AND “alias” =~ /^output_.*_cp_v1$/
GROUP BY “alias”, “cp_node”
)

When i ran this query, the timestamp which i am getting with the result is "01/01/1970 05:30:00
". I know this is because influx is using epoch 0 because of the use of aggregate functions. But i am not sure how to get current timestamp with this.
I tried adding “time()” with the GROUP BY clause, but still i am getting the same result.
SELECT sum(“metrics written”) FROM (
SELECT max(“metrics_written”) - min(“metrics_written”) as “metrics written”
FROM “tsesre_gms”.“anonymous”.“internal_write”
WHERE time > now() - 5m AND “alias” =~ /^output_.*_cp_v1$/
GROUP BY “alias”, “cp_node”, “time(5m)”
)

Would appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks.

Try this query to see the current timestamp:
SELECT now() AS current_time, sum("metrics written") AS total_metrics FROM (
  SELECT max("metrics_written") - min("metrics_written") AS "metrics written"
  FROM "tsesre_gms"."anonymous"."internal_write"
  WHERE time > now() - 5m AND "alias" =~ /^output_.*_cp_v1$/
  GROUP BY "alias", "cp_node"
)

Note the use of now() which returns current timestamp from the server in UTC, if you need local time then you will have to use timezone conversion function in your client side logic.
